How to populate this argument to fix error: Object literal may only specify known properties
I am trying to provide some arguments for a particular json object but I keep seeing this error:
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'createdData' does not exist in type '{ bookId: string; createdBooks: []; }[]

I don't really understand the layout of this method below so just wanted to ask how the argument should be populated. It's the [] that throws me at the end of this method
export async function settleBooks(
  createdData: { bookId: string; createdBooks: [] }[],
) {
  for (const book of createdData) {
    await settleBooksResulted(book.bookId, book.createdBooks);
  }
}

Below is how I am calling the method with the object included:
    const books = await settleBooks({
  createdData: {
    bookId: '8e3e7878-da38-43f4-a033-8cd9e37fa5c3',
    createdBooks: [
      {
        booksCreated: [
          {
            bookId: '8e3e7878-da38-43f4-a033-8cd9e37fa5c3',
            selectionId: 'd9767337-f9f6-4d05-83f4-48d5440eaa9b',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
});


https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#functions

createdData is the parameter name in the declaration of settleBooks -- it is not an object property.
Secondly, that parameter type is an array type -- notice the [] at the very end of { bookId: string; createdBooks: []; }[].
So in your object literal you should remove that createdData wrapper, and instead wrap as an array:
const books = await settleBooks([{
    bookId: '8e3e7878-da38-43f4-a033-8cd9e37fa5c3',
    createdBooks: [{
        booksCreated: [{
            bookId: '8e3e7878-da38-43f4-a033-8cd9e37fa5c3',
            selectionId: 'd9767337-f9f6-4d05-83f4-48d5440eaa9b',
        }],
    }],
}]);


Ah ok, issue now though (and this is what I saw before I added the CreatedData wrapper) is Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bookId' does not exist in type '{ bookId: string; createdBooks: []; }[]

Ah yes, I missed that it is an array type. I updated my answer.

Ah thank you very much
